# 500 error from controller even it is not reaching action method of the controller in asp.net

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.8

I have an API controller. When I run the code in visual studio and query, the swagger returns 500 errors, but when I debug it, it doesn't reach the controller action.

I also have a simple, no parameter, test endpoint that simply returns an `int` variable. Any method inside this controller file is not reached when this controller's endpoints are queried.

Comment: Simply viewing the Swagger documentation will not trigger any controller actions. In fact, viewing the Swagger UI doesn't even instantiate the controller. That means the 500 is coming from generating the page itself. You'd need to provide more details (what you're doing during startup, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found why this happened. It is because the service used in controller is not registered in DI container. In my opinion, it should just throw an exception instead of returning 500 without reaching to controller action. Anyway, I don't know why, but this worked for me after I added the service to DI.

Comment: An exception actually *is* being thrown. Throwing an exception in ASP.NET results in a 500.

Answer (score 0):

I actually forgot about this question of mine. But, anyway, there may be something useful for someone in this answer.

I found the answer: If there is some kind a service which is not registered in Dependency Injection, then there will be 500 error in swagger - for any request. Any call will be faced with thrown exception before reaching the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason that this may occur is because you have more than one endpoint with the same route, for example: `GET jobs/` resolving to two+ methods.